# Extract topics from SMS messages

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, topic-modeling, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I have a dataset of SMS messages which is ill formatted and sparse. I tried to use topic modeling to get all the possible topics in each message with the probability of each associated topic. I need the probability to be able to arrange or rank each message's topic.

What I am thinking about as an alternative solution is to label my dataset manually and use a supervised classification algorithm such as Naiive Bayes.
Here is a sample of my SMS messages which are sparse and contain spam content so that's why I assume topic modeling did not work well:

[image]

The challenges I am facing:

1. Is the alternative approach, using a supervised classification method, reasonable or should I rather keep an unsupervised method like topic modeling?
2. How should I process the data set: Should each message possess 1 category as label or can I assign multiple categories?
3. Is this a multi-label or multi-class classification problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the topics are, then use supervised Naive Bayes. Unsupervised learning can be used for class discovery.

Assigning multiple topics to a sample is not a problem.

Naive Bayes assigns a label to a sample based on the topic with the highest probability. Naturally, you can use the highest x probabilities (perhaps with a threshold) to assign multiple topics.

Comment: So to make sure I got it right If I am manually labeling the data I must give it more than 1 label for the training ? and as you say then I can use a hack to the Naiive Bayes to use the highest x topics ?

Comment: I have attached above a copy of my dataset to see how sparse and ill formatted it is , I want to make sure choosing not to use the topic modeling is right or not ?Because it's a set of 5000 message so manual labeling is not the best thing